# How can I access the elements of a linked list which is inside another struct?

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, linked-list

I want to count the number of elements present inside the DriverProfile linked list. And I want to do that by accessing the linked list through the struct ParkingLot.

```
//Declaring the linked list
struct DriverProfile{
    char name[20];
    int license_plate;
    struct DriverProfile *next_profile;
};
// Declaring the structure for parking lot containing the DriverProfile list identified by the *profiles pointer which is the pointer to the first element of the DriverProfile linked list

struct ParkingLot{
    struct DriverProfile *profiles ;
    int lotSize;
};
```

Comment: `parking_lot_pointer->profiles->name` and to get the next element: `parking_lot_pointer = parking_lot_pointer->next_profile`

Comment: If that is not what you are asking about then please be more specific in explaining which exact aspect of "access the elements" you are having trouble with.

Comment: Consider instead incrementing and decrementinig `arraySize` as you add and remove drivers to the parking lot. This is probably necessary to check against the `lotSize`. `numDrivers` might be a better name as it's not an array.

Comment: @kaylum I want to count the number of elements present inside the DriverProfile linked list. And I want to do that by accessing the linked list through the struct ParkingLot.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to traverse the linked list. Suggest you spend some time with your search engine. Linked list traversal explanations, including fully working sample code, is abundantly available.

Comment: @kaylum traversing and counting can be done. However, I'm confused if I can traverse the link list by accessing the struct Parking profile first?

Comment: Why would you think you can't? The traversal code won't care how you get access to the list. The `profiles` fields in the `ParkingLot` is the start of the linked list. Once you have that it's just a normal traversal. It's really not clear what your difficulty is and what you are actually asking.

Comment: If it makes it easier to understand, just create a pointer to the start of your list, e.g. `struct DriverProfile *p = ptr_to_some_ParkingLot->proifiles;` then you iterate and count with  `size_t n = 0; while (p) { n++; p = p->next_profile; }`